# ASP.NET Web API returning C# class

Tags: asp.net, jurassic

In Web API Controller action method returns C# class, like that:

```
public class ShipController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public Cell GetShip()
    {
        return new Cell(new ScriptEngine());
    }
}
```

Where Cell is my class, inherited from ObjectInstance from Jurassic JS library. When I call this action, ASP.NET tries to serialize my object to XML or JSON, and I get `System.InvalidOperationException`: "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'." I also tried to add [DataContract] attributes to class, as I found [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization), like that:

```
[DataContract]
public class Cell : ObjectInstance
{
    [DataMember]
    public int cellId;

    public Cell(ScriptEngine  engine) : base(engine)
    {
    }
}
```

But I still get error. How to make action return only my fields of class serialized, and not get into parent classes?

Comment: Can you access to `ObjectInstance` code?

Comment: Yes, it is [here](https://jurassic.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Jurassic/Library/Object/ObjectInstance.cs). The class tagged with [Serializable] attribute

Comment: Can you change it? Or you just use it?

Comment: I just use it, it's an open source library

Comment: [This is](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43347588/Ship.xml) the full error I get when visiting /api/Ship

Comment: OK, check my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to serialize the `Cell` class only, not its parent class, right? The solution is: **create a custom JSON converter**. Here is the code:

**Cell.cs**

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(CellJsonConverter))]
public class Cell : Parent
{
    public int CellId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Cell(int id) : base(id)
    {
        CellId = id;
        Name = "This is a name";
    }
}
```

**CellJsonConverter.cs**

```
public class CellJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var cell = (Cell) value;

        writer.WriteStartObject();

        writer.WritePropertyName("cellId");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, cell.CellId);

        writer.WritePropertyName("name");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, cell.Name);

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Cell);
    }
}
```

When you call your API, you will get: `{"cellId":10,"name":"This is a name"}`.

`JsonConverter` is from `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Feel free to ask if there's something unclear to you :)